# Get matching fields in a find() with $or operand

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, minimongo

I am doing a find() operation on my collection like this:

```js
db.posts.find({
    "$or":[
        { "name": keywords },
        { "description": keywords },
        { "tags": keywords }
    ]
});
```

keywords is a RegEx, everything works great.

But I was wondering if there was a way in MongoDB to know which field matched `name` or `description` or `tags`. Or a way to count matching fields.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are relying on the count of matching fields to sort result, I think text index in mongo 2.6 is a better choice. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: thans for your comment.
if I can add more details: on one result that matches the result, I am looking to know if it matched on `name`,`description` or `tags`.
I want to do it on an individual level on each result to help me sort them by "accuracy"
Did not see anything like this on index-text.

Comment: text index is more like a simple search engine. you are able to control the **weight** of each field, then control the sort order. Have a look at [this section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using Meteor with minimongo and it seems that text search is not implemented. :(